# C# - Save Icon of executable files

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I written a program that save icon of executable files. when I get icon of executable files by ExtractAssociatedIcon method and save it, the quality of output icon be **low quality**. what can I Do?

```
var ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"c:/test.exe");
FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(string.Format("{0}{1}", Path.GetTempPath(), "icon" + counter + ".ico"), System.IO.FileMode.Create);
ico.Save(stream);
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
```

Comment: This is a *very* common question, please search for answers before you ask for help.  Type "extractassociatedicon" in the Search box at the upper right of this page.

Comment: http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/164

Comment: I had searched extractassociatedicon but can't find a true answer.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko it couldn't solve my problem. when I save icon file it will be low quality icon

Answer (score 2):

It is not easy. You must use SystemImageList. It is not supported by .NET framework, so you must use unsafe methods to access system. Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon returns only 32x32 resolution.

If you are really into doing that, this is a good start: http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/SysImageList/article.asp

UPDATE: if you want only for .exe files and you don't need support for Windows XP, you may also use Windows API Codepack http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack and get thumbnail of item at required size.

Answer (score -1):

You should read this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx)

16x16 or 32x32 is the standard size of ico. You cant expect a 32x32image to be very HD

> The Shell Icon Size value allows using larger icons in place of
>   32×32 icons and the Shell Small Icon Size value allows using custom
>   sizes in place of 16×16 icons.[3] Thus, even prior to Windows XP, a
>   single icon file could store images of any size from 1×1 pixel up to
>   256×256 pixels (including non-square sizes) with 16, 256, 65535, or
>   16.7 million colors; but the shell could not display very large sized icons.

Comment: Is there another way to extract HQ Icon of exe files?

Comment: When there is no HD image than how can you extract it brother. ICO image is of 16x16 and HD image is of 1280×720. So do the maths for difference in sizes